# How to tell my computer to run a program on my fpga

Tags: fpga

i have an important question, which I cant figure it out.

lets say I'm designing an fpga which all he is doing is multiplying matrices,Im writing a matlab program and I want my fpga to use the fpga for (some/all) calculations, how can it be done?

I thought about few things:
1.burn the matlab program (somehow, bit/hex/(happy to here for another way)) on the fpga SDRAM  - well this is more like a bypass than a solution..

2.build a compiler for the fpga - I have a lot of motivation, but I'm not superman..

Even the ideas above, Im not sure about them and I  (still) don't know how to implement them, I dont know what's possible and what's not, is it even possible to make the fpga "help"? (sounds like a waste of time), or the entire programm must run ont he fpga?

when Im thinking about the fpga helping the cpu I'm thinking I need to make something like a controller between the both of them..But again, Im lost in the dark.

That's why I need your help, Ill be happy to ear your knowledge.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm sorry , probably I wasn't clear enough, Im not really trying to design a circuit on fpga to multiple matrices, I'm trying to **learn**(!).
Im a fourth year in EE , and im interested to learn how fpga works, I'm writing in systemVerilog.
Now for those of you who wonders: "Your a Fourth year in EE and dont know how to use FPGA???" , then yes... all we learn theory theory theory.

And Marcus Müller , yes.. I know nothing about FPGA, but I'm learning, and that's why I asked, to learn.. I thought that's one of the purposes for this Forum..

definitely the worst forum there is...

Comment: Most common method is to have the FPGA connected to the PC via an internal PCIe slot. There are many off the shelf boards you can use. Then you probably have to write a driver in C/C++ to interface from the fpga to matlab. Using that driver, you can create a .m file that you call to offload specific complex calculations to the fpga.

Comment: Consider using a GPU for matrix math... cheaper, and I believe matlab has many drivers for them, or use OpenCL...

Comment: Yes, if you're doing floating point matrix multiplication a GPU will outperform a FPGA even before accounting for the difficulties in getting the data in and out.

Comment: Option 3: Start the calculation in Matlab *now*, and by the time you have implemented the FPGA solution, the CPU will have the answer.

Comment: your question really indicates you don't have experience with FPGAs: they don't *run* programs. You can *configure* them to be a specific giant logic circuit. Programs run on processors.

Comment: I'm doing this on fpga to learn..
Im not really trying to multiple matrices.. that's why I used the expression :"lets say.."

Comment: "your question really indicates you don't have experience with FPGAs: they don't run programs. You can configure them to be a specific giant logic circuit."
That's part of what Im asking, how can I make them and use them as functional logic circuit

Comment: "definitely the worst forum there is..." This isn't a forum, it's a question and answer site. You come here to get specific answers to specific questions, not to be taught the basics from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no simple, easy way to do this (unless your fpga happens to support OpenCL, and even then...). Judging by your post, it doesn't look like you have much experience with FPGAs, and if that is the case, you're really going to struggle to do this.

To connect your FPGA to your computer, pretty much anything but PCIe will be to slow, so you'd need to buy a FPGA PCIe card. Next, you'd need to write a driver to let your computer talk to the FPGA over PCIe, and you'll either need to write or find a PCIe IP to let your FPGA use PCIe (and if you use someone else's, they're frequently rather expensive). Then, you'll need to again write or find another piece of IP that will let the PCIe controller communicate with your matrix core. Finally, you will either need to generate the matrix core from matlab using HDL Coder, or write one yourself. Also, unless you're superman, any IP you write isn't going to work the first time, so you'll need to write test benches to verify that each piece of the design works before actually putting it on the FPGA.

Realistically, I'd follow MadHatter's advice for using a GPU, unless your matrices are easily convertible to fixed point, the GPU is going to give you much less headaches than trying to put your design on an FPGA.